# Change a cell color if its value is found in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to VBA and do have some experience, but am at a brick wall.

I have a list of supervisors and employees that I need VBA to scan through to make sure that someone is not reporting to themselves or reporting to themselves some where down the line (ex. John Smith report to Kevin Spacey who reports to John Smith) and then I need excel to change that cells color if it is found that there is a "circular reporting reference" between the ones behind it.

In my screen shot line 3 is an example of a "circular reporting reference" and I would need the Secondary Super cell highlighted

Example of reporting:

[image: Example of reporting]

If Then statements but did not work

Answer (score 0):

Using `Conditional Formatting` to highlight cells

- Select B2:E7
- Home > Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules > New Rule

[image]

---

If you prefer to use VBA code ...

- Load data into an array to improve efficiency
- Collect all duplicated cells with a range object
- Apply highlight color on it all at once

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, sKey As String
    Dim arrData, rngRes As Range
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    arrData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        objDic.RemoveAll
        For j = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
            sKey = arrData(i, j)
            If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
                If rngRes Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngRes = Cells(i, j)
                Else
                    Set rngRes = Application.Union(rngRes, Cells(i, j))
                End If
            Else
                objDic(sKey) = ""
            End If
        Next
    Next i
    If Not rngRes Is Nothing Then rngRes.Interior.Color = vbYellow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution with VBA. What code dose is loop through each row starting from row 2. It sets CurrentRowText variable to empty string, at start of each row and then adds the cells value to the variable. If the value is already there it highlights that cell.

```
Sub highlightMatching()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim currentRowText As String
    Dim currentValue As String
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Dim rng As Range
    
    For i = 2 To sh.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
        currentRowText = ""
        For j = 1 To sh.UsedRange.Columns.Count
            currentValue = "$$" & Trim(sh.Cells(i, j).Value) & "$$"
            If InStr(currentRowText, currentValue) > 0 Then
                sh.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End If
            currentRowText = currentRowText & currentValue
        
        Next
        Next
    
End Sub
```

[image]